# Choose constants a and b so that the function is continuous everywhere!

Tags: limits, continuity

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
a-x,  & \text{if $x \le -1$ } \\
\frac{x^2+2x+b}{x+1} & \text{if $x \gt -1$ }  \\
\end{cases}$$

I try:
$a-x$ is continous everywhere for every $a$ when $x\le1$.
The other one however is continous only when $b=1$. Am I correct?

So now we should choose $a$ so that $f$ is continious everywhere. Which means:

$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=f(-1)=\lim_{x\to -1^-}f(x)$$ 
  As we approach from left:
$$\lim_{x\to -1^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -1^-}a-x=a+1$$
$$f(-1)=a+1$$
As we approach from right:
$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}=notDefined$$

Im stuck now! Can you please help? How may I continue? 
Is this the right way of solving this type of question?
One thing that comes to my head is that $a+1=0$ so $a=-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right. Note that
$$\lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -1^+} \dfrac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1} = \lim_{x \to -1^+} \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x+1} = \lim_{x \to -1^+} x+1 = 0$$
(In fact this is why we choose $b=1$.)

Comment: Thank you Marvis. How can I be sure that it is continuos everywhere? Shall I graf and see?

Comment: @Alex90 A linear function (in your case $a-x$) is continuous everywhere. And so is a rational expression, except at zeros of the denominator. Hence, the only place where there could be a possible discontinuity is at $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to be continuous, for $b=1$ the limit will surely exist, on the right hand side, now we only need to chose $a$ such that the limits are the same.

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2 +2x+b}{x+1}&=\frac{x^2+2x+1+b-1}{x+1}\\
&=\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1} +\frac{b-1}{x+1} \\
&=\frac{(x+1)^2}{x+1}+\frac{b-1}{x+1}\\
&=x+1+\frac{b-1}{x+1}
\end{align*}

So we see the limit for $x\to -1$ only can exist when $b=1$. When $b=1$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to -1} x+1=0$$
Hence $b=1$, and $a=-1$.

For $x\neq -1$ your funciton is polynomial and hence continuous.

Comment: No. I just solved it as Marvis said. And I get a=-1 and b=1. And the graph is continous everywhere! a and b are not equal. Graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+piecewise%5B%7B%7B1-x%2Cx%3C%3D-1%7D%2C%7B%28%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%2C%28x%3E-1%29%7D%7D%5D

Comment: oh right sry $a=-1$ is right made a mistake

Comment: np. Thanks for helping Dominic! Have a great day.

Comment: @Alex90 but the graph is not continuous, cause continuousis for functions not for graphs :)

Comment: The graph is not cont. because I have set a and b to 1. In this one  I have set a=-1 and b=1. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+piecewise%5B%7B%7B-1-x%2Cx%3C%3D-1%7D%2C%7B%28%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%2C%28x%3E-1%29%7D%7D%5D

Comment: @Alex90 no you missunterstood, a graph can't be continuous at all, only a fucntion can be continuous

Comment: Ahhaaaa! :) Yes you are right!